# Dropping list of rows from multi-level pandas dataframe where first two levels have duplicate indices

Tags: pandas

I would like to drop a list of row indices from a multi-level data frame, where the first two levels have duplicate entries. I imagine it is possible to do this without a loop, but thus far I have not found this.

I have attempted to use the pd.drop function by providing a list row index combinations, though this does not have the desired effect. As an example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
def mklbl(prefix, n):
     return ["%s%s" % (prefix, i) for i in range(n)]


def src_rec(n, mult):
    src = [[no]*mult for no in range(1,n)]

    src = [item for sublist in src for item in sublist]

    rec = [no for no in range(1,n)]*mult

    return src, rec

src, rec = src_rec(4,4)


miindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([src*2,
                                   rec*2,
                                   mklbl('C', 24)])

dfmi = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(len(miindex) * 2)\
               .reshape((len(miindex), 2)),
                index=miindex)
```

## I would like to drop all rows with index values (1,2,:) and (2,3,:)

```
As = [1, 2]
Bs = [2, 3]

dfmi.drop(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([As,Bs]))
```

The result of this is:

```
          0   1
1 1 C0    0   1
2 1 C18  36  37
  2 C19  38  39
3 3 C20  40  41
  1 C21  42  43
  2 C22  44  45
  3 C23  46  47
```

While my desired result is:

```
          0   1
1 1 C0    0   1
  3 C2    4   5
  1 C3    6   7
2 2 C4    8   9
  1 C6   12  13
  2 C7   14  15
3 3 C8   16  17
  1 C9   18  19
  2 C10  20  21
  3 C11  22  23
1 1 C12  24  25
  3 C14  28  29
  1 C15  30  31
2 2 C16  32  33
  1 C18  36  37
  2 C19  38  39
3 3 C20  40  41
  1 C21  42  43
  2 C22  44  45
  3 C23  46  47
```

An example of this in a loop is;

```
for A, B in zip(As, Bs):
    dfmi_drop_idx = CCdata.loc[(A, B, slice(None)), :].index
    dfmi.drop(dfmi_drop_idx, inplace=True, errors='raise')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with test membership by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
m = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([As,Bs])
df = dfmi[~dfmi.reset_index(level=2, drop=True).index.isin(m)]
print (df)
          0   1
1 1 C0    0   1
  3 C2    4   5
  1 C3    6   7
2 2 C4    8   9
  1 C6   12  13
  2 C7   14  15
3 3 C8   16  17
  1 C9   18  19
  2 C10  20  21
  3 C11  22  23
1 1 C12  24  25
  3 C14  28  29
  1 C15  30  31
2 2 C16  32  33
  1 C18  36  37
  2 C19  38  39
3 3 C20  40  41
  1 C21  42  43
  2 C22  44  45
  3 C23  46  47
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, That sure is quicker when applying it to 300K rows ;-)